# D3: Noobie, Trying to set up a legend, unsure why it's not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm displaying a temperature map based on year and month. I want to display a legend at the bottom of the chart to show what temperature each color corresponds to. Can someone help me understand how to do this and what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code for this specific part:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(colors)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => {
      return 300 + i*legendWidth})
      .attr("y", h - 50)
      .attr("width", legendWidth)
      .attr("height", legendHeight)
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors[i])
      .attr("fill-opacity", "0.5");
```

Expected output:
[image]

Currently getting:
[image]

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/dmjJWg?editors=0110

Full JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  req=new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET","https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/global-temperature.json", true);
  req.send();
  req.onload=function(){
    const dataset=JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    const data = dataset.monthlyVariance;
    const w = 1000;
    const h = 600;
    const padding = 92;
    const boxWidth = Math.ceil(w / (data.length / 12)); // width / number of years
    const boxHeight = Math.floor((h - padding - padding) / 12) + 4; // height / 12
    // need +4 above because 1753 months != 2015 months
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    const colors = ["#3910ed", "#3479f9", "#2fc0ed", "#36edba", "#e2fff7", "#fff1a5", "#d6bc2c", "#f9a86d", "#c17036", "#f26060", "#561212"];
    const legendWidth = 30;
    const legendHeight = 20;

    const svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1753, 2015])
    .range([padding, w - padding]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, 12])
    .range([padding, h - padding]);

    let tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip");      

    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale(d.year))
      .attr("y", (d, i) => yScale(d.month - 1))
      .attr("width", boxWidth)
      .attr("height", boxHeight)
      .attr("fill", (d) => 8.66 + d.variance < 3 ? colors[0] : 8.66 + d.variance < 4 ? colors[1] : 8.66 + d.variance < 5 ? colors[2] : 8.66 + d.variance < 6 ? colors[3] : 8.66 + d.variance < 7 ? colors[4] : 8.66 + d.variance < 8 ? colors[5] : 8.66 + d.variance < 9 ? colors[6] : 8.66 + d.variance < 10 ?  colors[7] : 8.66 + d.variance < 11 ? colors[8] : 8.66 + d.variance < 12 ? colors[9] : colors[10])
      .attr("fill-opacity", "0.5")
      .on("mousemove", (d) => {
        tooltip
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 +"px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
          .style("display", "inline-block")
          .html("<span>" + d.year + " &#8212; " + months[d.month-1] + "<br/>" + Math.round((8.33 + d.variance)*100)/100 + " ℃<br/>" + d.variance + " ℃</span>")
       })
        .on("mouseout", (d) => {
          tooltip
            .style("display", "none");
        });

    svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(colors)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d, i) => {
      return 300 + i*legendWidth})
      .attr("y", h - 50)
      .attr("width", legendWidth)
      .attr("height", legendHeight)
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors[i])
      .attr("fill-opacity", "0.5");


    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(months)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text((month) => month)
      .attr("x", padding - 5)
      .attr("y", (month, i) => (padding + (i*boxHeight) - boxHeight / 3)) // divided by 3 instead of 2 b/c y attribute aligns by bottom of text and I want it to be centered
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    // .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // so it's 2015, not 2,015

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("text") // subhead
      .attr("x", w/2)
      .attr("y", 20)
      .attr("font-size", "25px")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("1753 - 2015");

    svg.append("text") // subhead
      .attr("x", w/2)
      .attr("y", 35)
      .attr("font-size", "12px")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Temperatures are in Celsius and reported as anomalies relative to the Jan 1951-Dec 1980 average.");

    svg.append("text") // subhead
      .attr("x", w/2)
      .attr("y", 50)
      .attr("font-size", "12px")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Estimated Jan 1951-Dec 1980 absolute temperature ℃: 8.66 +/- 0.07.");
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue occurs because of how you create the legend:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(colors)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  ...
```

The first line selects the rectangles that are already in the DOM, the rectangles that form the visualization/chart.

The second line updates the data for this selection. Since there are more rectangles in the selection than there are colors in the data array, there is nothing to enter, your enter selection is empty and consequently nothing is appended.

Since you don't apply any update and you just use an (empty) enter selection to append and style the legend, nothing visibly changes in the visualization.

Instead, you could use `svg.selectAll(null)` (or `svg.selectAll()`), this will create an empty selection, so that an item is entered for each item in the data array. Here's an updated [plunkr](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqPeQa?editors=0110).

Comment: `selectAll()` does work, but it looks like a getter... That's why I prefer `null`.